# How do I Instantiate a class from Main class?

Tags: java, class

I am creating a program for my computer science program. I am trying to call a class called "StockBarChart". How would I call this class from my main class?

Edit: I have posted the code below
In this class I have created a bar chart. I am not quite sure where I have gone wrong.

```
public class StockBarChart extends JPanel {
    private double[] values;

    private String[] names;

    private String title;

    public StockBarChart(double[] v, String[] n, String t) {
        names = n;
        values = v;
        title = t;
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        if (values == null || values.length == 0)
            return;
        double minValue = 0;
        double maxValue = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
            if (minValue > values[i])
                minValue = values[i];
            if (maxValue < values[i])
                maxValue = values[i];
        }

        Dimension d = getSize();
        int clientWidth = d.width;
        int clientHeight = d.height;
        int barWidth = clientWidth / values.length;

        Font titleFont = new Font("SansSerif", Font.BOLD, 20);
        FontMetrics titleFontMetrics = g.getFontMetrics(titleFont);
        Font labelFont = new Font("SansSerif", Font.PLAIN, 10);
        FontMetrics labelFontMetrics = g.getFontMetrics(labelFont);

        int titleWidth = titleFontMetrics.stringWidth(title);
        int y = titleFontMetrics.getAscent();
        int x = (clientWidth - titleWidth) / 2;
        g.setFont(titleFont);
        g.drawString(title, x, y);

        int top = titleFontMetrics.getHeight();
        int bottom = labelFontMetrics.getHeight();
        if (maxValue == minValue)
            return;
        double scale = (clientHeight - top - bottom) / (maxValue - minValue);
        y = clientHeight - labelFontMetrics.getDescent();
        g.setFont(labelFont);

        for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
            int valueX = i * barWidth + 1;
            int valueY = top;
            int height = (int) (values[i] * scale);
            if (values[i] >= 0)
                valueY += (int) ((maxValue - values[i]) * scale);
            else {
                valueY += (int) (maxValue * scale);
                height = -height;
            }

            g.setColor(Color.red);
            g.fillRect(valueX, valueY, barWidth - 2, height);
            g.setColor(Color.black);
            g.drawRect(valueX, valueY, barWidth - 2, height);
            int labelWidth = labelFontMetrics.stringWidth(names[i]);
            x = i * barWidth + (barWidth - labelWidth) / 2;
            g.drawString(names[i], x, y);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] argv) {
        try{
            String breadStockBeforeTrim = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("bread.txt")));
            String breadStock = breadStockBeforeTrim.trim();
            int breadNumber = Integer.parseInt(breadStock);
            String browniesStockBeforeTrim = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("brownies.txt")));
            String browniesStock = browniesStockBeforeTrim.trim();
            int browniesNumber = Integer.parseInt(browniesStock);

            JFrame f = new JFrame();
            f.setSize(400, 300);
            double[] values = new double[3];
            String[] names = new String[3];
            values[0] = 1;
            names[0] = "Item 1";

            values[1] = breadNumber;
            names[1] = "Item 2";

            values[2] = browniesNumber;
            names[2] = "Item 3";

            f.getContentPane().add(new 


                StockBarChart(values, names, "title"));

            WindowListener wndCloser = new WindowAdapter() {
                    public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                        System.exit(0);
                    }
                };
            f.addWindowListener(wndCloser);
            f.setVisible(true);
        }catch(IOException b){
            b.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `StockBarChart stockBarChart = new StockBarChart()` from here you can call any method like `stockBarChart.someMethod();`

Comment: You don't "call" a class

Comment: You seem to be slightly confused with your terminology. You can't "call" classes, however classes can contain "callable" things named methods. Maybe the word you're looking for is "instantiate"?

Comment: It won't compile and comes up with the error message "constructor StockBarChart in class StockBarChart cannot be applied to given types; required: double[], java.lang.String[], java.lang.String; found no arguments; reason: actual and formal argument list differ in length"

Comment: Sounds like you're trying to do `new StockBarChart();`. You need to pass some arguments in (put the required arguments inside the parentheses).

Comment: The error explains exactly what is wrong, the constructor needs a double array, a string array, and a string, you did not provide these. So instead of `new StockBarChart()` you need `new StockBarChart(yourDoubleArray, yourStringArray, yourString)`

Comment: `StockBarChart` -- can you edit your question and post the code of this class. The `constructor` is expecting two parameters which are a `double` type array and a `String` type array and`String` type - respectively. So your class instantiation should look like `StockBarChart stockBarChart = new StockBarChart(doubleValueArray, stringValueArray, stringValue)`

Comment: This has solved my problem. Thank you so much for your help! And thank you for also helping me with my terminology.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is simple:

Here is the signature of the Constructor of your class `StockBarChart`:

```
public StockBarChart(double[] v, String[] n, String t) {
        names = n;
        values = v;
        title = t;
    }
```

Whenever you want to instantiate any of your class, you init it via the constructor. Even when a constructor is not written explicitly, java assigns a constructor (empty constructor) by default.

In your case, when you instantiate the class, it expects a few values which are mapped through the constructor and are necessary for the object to operate on  variables, via the class methods.

Simply providing those parameters will solve your problem.

So to say, you should instantiate the Class like below:

`StockBarChart stockBarChart = new StockBarChart(doubleArray,stringArray,stringValue)`

Comment: Not to be nit-picky but I would say "Only when a constructor is not written explicitly" instead of "Even". I have a feeling his issue is assuming that the default constructor is always provided .

Answer (score 0):

If the error message says that the required types are double[] String[] and String that means that you need to give the constructor the needed parameters.

It seems that your class StockBarChart has a constructor such as:

```
public StockBarChart(double[] v, String[] n, String t) {}
```

and that means that when instantiating the class, you need to give it those double[], String[] and String:

```
StockBarChart stockBarChart = new StockBarChart(someSetParameterOfDouble[]Type, someString[]Parameter, someString);
```

You initialize those and given them to the constructor.

Comment: I am unsure as to what the variables are in my code. Every time I put a value in it says "array required but variable found"